# Add column and nb of element rep depending on conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
   Groups Names COL1  COL2  COL3        COL4
1      G1   SP1    1 0.400 0.500   Sequence1
2      G1   SP1    1 0.004 0.005   Sequence2
3      G1   SP1    0 0.004 0.005   Sequence3
4      G1   SP2    0 0.400 0.005 Sequence123
5      G1   SP2    0 0.004 0.500  Sequence14
6      G1   SP3    0 0.005 0.006  Sequence15
7      G1   SP5    1 0.400 0.006  Sequence16
8      G1   SP6    1 0.008 0.002  Sequence20
10     G2   Sp1    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence17
11     G2   SP1    0 0.050 0.600  Sequence18
12     G2   SP1    0 0.400 0.600   Sequence3
13     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence22
14     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence23
15     G2   SP5    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence16
16     G2   SP6    0 0.003 0.002  Sequence21
17     G2   SP7    0 0.560 0.760  Sequence67
18     G3   SP5    0 0.87  0.767  Sequence16
```

and I would like to add a new column `COL5`

Where I add a 1 if for each Names in Groups, we have shared Sequences within groups.
For instance let's look at the G1.

The `SP1` has the `Sequence3` that is present in `G1` and in `G2`, so I put  the number of rep for `row 3 and 12`. here (2)

Same for `SP5` which has `Sequence15` in `G1` and `Sequence15` in `G2` and `G3`, (here the number of rep is 3)

So for all the dataframe I should get:

```
   Groups Names COL1  COL2  COL3        COL4 COL5
1      G1   SP1    1 0.400 0.500   Sequence1 0
2      G1   SP1    1 0.004 0.005   Sequence2 0
3      G1   SP1    0 0.004 0.005   Sequence3 2
4      G1   SP2    0 0.400 0.005 Sequence123 0
5      G1   SP2    0 0.004 0.500  Sequence14 0
6      G1   SP3    0 0.005 0.006  Sequence15 0
7      G1   SP5    1 0.400 0.006  Sequence16 3
8      G1   SP6    1 0.008 0.002  Sequence20 0
10     G2   Sp1    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence17 0
11     G2   SP1    0 0.050 0.600  Sequence18 0
12     G2   SP1    0 0.400 0.600   Sequence3 2
13     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence22 0
14     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence23 0
15     G2   SP5    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence16 3
16     G2   SP6    0 0.003 0.002  Sequence21 0
17     G2   SP7    0 0.560 0.760  Sequence67 0
18     G3   SP5    0 0.87  0.767  Sequence16 3
```

Here is the `dput`:

```
dput(test_df)
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,3L), .Label = c("G1", "G2","G3"), class = "factor"), 
    Names = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L,5L), .Label = c("Sp1", "SP1", "SP2", 
    "SP3", "SP5", "SP6", "SP7","SP5"), class = "factor"), COL1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ,0L), COL2 = c(0.4, 0.004, 0.004, 0.4, 0.004, 0.005, 0.4, 0.008, 
    0.004, 0.05, 0.4, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.56,0.87), COL3 = c(0.5, 
    0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.5, 0.006, 0.006, 0.002, 0.005, 0.6, 
    0.6, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.002, 0.76,0.767 ), COL4 = structure(c(1L, 
    8L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 
    14L), .Label = c("Sequence1", "Sequence123", "Sequence14", 
    "Sequence15", "Sequence16", "Sequence17", "Sequence18", "Sequence2", 
    "Sequence20", "Sequence21", "Sequence22", "Sequence23", "Sequence3", 
    "Sequence67","Sequence16"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17","18"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count number of unique `Groups` for each `COL4` value and assign 1/0 value if they are more than 1.

```
library(dplyr)
test_df %>% 
 group_by(COL4, Names) %>% 
 mutate(COL5 = {ind = n_distinct(Groups); if(ind > 1) ind else 0})


#   Groups Names  COL1  COL2  COL3 COL4         COL5
#   <chr>  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 G1     SP1       1 0.4   0.5   Sequence1       0
# 2 G1     SP1       1 0.004 0.005 Sequence2       0
# 3 G1     SP1       0 0.004 0.005 Sequence3       2
# 4 G1     SP2       0 0.4   0.005 Sequence123     0
# 5 G1     SP2       0 0.004 0.5   Sequence14      0
# 6 G1     SP3       0 0.005 0.006 Sequence15      0
# 7 G1     SP5       1 0.4   0.006 Sequence16      3
# 8 G1     SP6       1 0.008 0.002 Sequence20      0
# 9 G2     Sp1       0 0.004 0.005 Sequence17      0
#10 G2     SP1       0 0.05  0.6   Sequence18      0
#11 G2     SP1       0 0.4   0.6   Sequence3       2
#12 G2     SP2       0 0.004 0.005 Sequence22      0
#13 G2     SP2       0 0.004 0.005 Sequence23      0
#14 G2     SP5       0 0.004 0.005 Sequence16      3
#15 G2     SP6       0 0.003 0.002 Sequence21      0
#16 G2     SP7       0 0.56  0.76  Sequence67      0
#17 G3     SP5       0 0.87  0.767 Sequence16      3
```

Or in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_df)[, COL5 := {ind = uniqueN(Groups); if(ind > 1) ind else 0}, .(COL4, Names)]
```

and in base R :

```
test_df$COL5 <- with(test_df, as.integer(ave(as.character(Groups), COL4, Names,
                         FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))))
test_df$COL5[test_df$COL5 == 1] <- 0
```

Comment: You do not take into account the Names column in the code ? I mean Sequence21 is both in G1 and G2 but in different species (SP1 and SP6)

Comment: Ohh..I see. I think your input and output dataframe shown is different. For example Sequence21 is only once in input but twice in output. Probably, adding `Names` column in `group_by` would sort it out.

Comment: In fact I changed a little bit the question, now instead of adding just 1 or 2 I would like to add the number of rep (so minimum 2 for instance) and zero if there is not rep (I updated the table)

Comment: Why is `Sequence15` 2? It is present only once.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
test_df %>% 
  group_by(COL4, Names) %>% 
  mutate(COL5 = n_distinct(Groups) * (n_distinct(Groups) > 1))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_df)[, COL5 := uniqueN(Groups) * (uniqueN(Groups) > 1), .(COL4, Names)]
```